# How to cache cloning git repo in install.sh

Tags: python, git, docker, caching

I'm building a docker for my Flask application. In the application, I'm using a python module cloned from github. Let's call it module A. The module A consists of another module cloned from git, let's call it a module B. The module A has an `install.sh` script, in which the module B is cloned. The module B consists of another module (C) cloned from git and it is cloned from an `install.sh` script from the module B. So in my dockerfile I run `install.sh` of the module A, it runs `install.sh` of module B and it runs `install.sh` of module C.

```
flask_app
├── Dockerfile
├── A
|   ├── install.sh
|   ├── B
|       ├── install.sh
|       ├── C
|           ├── install.sh
```

I need to change some code in the module A to fit my application, so I clone it manually and change the code.

In the dockerfile I use

```
RUN cd ./A && ./install.sh
```

which installs all of the needed modules. The problem is, it does not use cache when I build the docker another time. It is a huge problem, because building the module C takes 1 hour. How can I make docker cache this command?

This is the whole dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7

RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN apt-get update && \
      apt-get -y install sudo

ADD ./requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ADD . /app

RUN cd ./A && ./install.sh

ENV WEB_CONCURRENCY 5

CMD gunicorn app:app
```

Comment: It will cache it, provided all of the steps before it were cached.  Can you include the complete Dockerfile?

Comment: @DavidMaze I added the dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

The Docker layer caching is pretty linear: if anything changes in a particular step, neither that step nor anything after it will be cached.

In particular, in these two lines:

```
ADD . /app
RUN cd ./A && ./install.sh
```

If anything at all changes anywhere in your source tree, that will cause the `ADD` step to not use the cache, which means the `RUN` step won't either.

If the `A` directory changes infrequently, then you can just copy and run that in its own step:

```
COPY ./A/ /app/A/
RUN cd ./A && ./install.sh

COPY . /app
```

(This is the same pattern as what you already have for the `requirements.txt` file, for basically the same reason.  I generally prefer `COPY` to `ADD` unless I explicitly want automatic URL fetching and archive extraction.)